# what could cause jquery to work on JSFIDDLE but not LIVE SITE

Tags: jquery

ok, i  know this has been asked a million times, but im not debugging anything (i THINK).  Im using very simple code and it seems very straight forward.  on load, hide a div... and when another div is clicked, fadeIN() that div.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.menu').hide();
    $('.menuWrapper').hide();
});

$('.exp').click(function() {
    $('.menu').fadeIn(300);
    $('.menuWrapper').fadeIn(300);
});
```

Pretty straight forward. from the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CJxN3/
to the site: http://theparadox.me/sandbox/

Comment: Probbably other codes that's affecting this process which is not included in your fiddle. :/

Comment: no, i set a sandbox on my site http://www.theparadox.me/sandbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code

```
$('.exp').click(function() {
    $('.menu').fadeIn(300);
    $('.menuWrapper').fadeIn(300);
});
```

should be within `$(document).ready(function(){{});`

Move the block inside like this for the listeners to be applied after document has been loaded. By not doing so, the listeners are not applied to the nodes.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.menu').hide();
    $('.menuWrapper').hide();

    $('.exp').click(function() {
        $('.menu').fadeIn(300);
        $('.menuWrapper').fadeIn(300);
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry Im a bit new to jQuery.

Comment: no worries. Fiddle adds the document.ready for you, when you select the javascript library to be jquery. so it is working on fiddle